# SpringBoot + Thymeleaf - upload MultipartFile in form

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, multipart

I've done the following Thymeleaf form which takes some fields and a .pdf CV file

Form: [link](https://textdoc.co/n3zvmy4aEjT8BN1W)

There is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/interview")
public class InterviewController {

@PostMapping(path = "/create", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> createInterview(@RequestBody @ModelAttribute CreateInterviewTO createInterviewTO) {
    ErrorRTO errorRTO = checkErrorsInsertInterview.validate(createInterviewTO);
    //...Other
}

}
```

And at the end, DTO class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateInterviewTO {

private String site;
private String candidateName;
private String candidateSurname;
private Date candidateBirth;
private String mail;
private String eduQualification;
private String candidateType;
private String interviewType;
private String enterpriseId;
private MultipartFile curriculum;
}
```

When I send the request, I receive the following error:
w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved `[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]`

**UPDATE**: when I sent request, curriculum DTO attribute is null.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Can you post the full code of your dto and your thymeleaf form? I suspect it is related to dto not having proper constructor or getter/setters. Are you using jackson?

Comment: @NullishByte updated the main thread.